# Attempt to concatenate global 'q101' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i like to load text form a external .lua file in to my game, here is a little test i setup to test the principal, i know if i give **"q101"** numbers like so **"q101 = 123456"** the code displays the numbers **123456** but i don't understand why it doesn't with letters.

Can some one please explain how i can do this is the right way, as this is clearly not the way of doing it

```
q101 = HELLO

Q1 = display.newText("".. q101, 160, 20, MYRIADPRO, 30)
Q1:setTextColor( 255, 255, 2552)
Q1.x = display.contentWidth/2  
Q1.y = display.contentHeight/2
screenGroup:insert(Q1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line `q101 = HELLO` is setting the value of the `q101` variable to the value of the `HELLO` variable. And as the global variable with that name has no value (as it has never been defined) you are assigning `nil` to your `q101` variable.

Numbers cannot be variables and so do not work that way.

You want to assign the string `"HELLO"` to your variable: `q101 = "HELLO"`.

Comment: i have one more little question, i'f updated the original question

Comment: `q1` is a string `"q201"`. You then use that in your display call. So you display that string. You want that used as a variable. You need to look it up in the globals table `_G[q1]` or use a local table instead of `_G` and do the same sort of lookup.