# Attempt to load text from a string

Tags: lua, coronasdk

If it try to load this is shows **"q201"** and not the desired **"Display 2"** any thoughts on this ?

```
TestCount = 2
q101 = "Display 1"
q201 = "Display 2"
q1 = "q"..TestCount.."01"


QD1 = display.newText("".. q1, 160, 20, MYRIADPRO, 30)
QD1:setTextColor( 255, 255, 2552)
QD1.x = display.contentWidth/2  
QD1.y = display.contentHeight/2
screenGroup:insert(QD1)
```

i looked at local table but that didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493566/attempt-to-concatenate-global-q101-a-nil-value#comment37917605_24493712) on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493566/attempt-to-concatenate-global-q101-a-nil-value). You need to use your `q1` variable as the *key* into a table to get the value of your `q201` variable. As written your code is using it as a string.

You either need to use `display.newText(_G[q1], ...)` or use a local table `local qs = {}` with which you use:

```
qs.q101 = "Display 1"
qs.q201 = "Display 2"
```

and then use as `display.newText(qs[q1], ...)`.

Comment: i see :D "Q1 = display.newText(_G[q1],  160, 20, MYRIADPRO, 30)" works

Comment: Yes, though generally using global variables this way is an indication that you are doing something wrong and that you should either use a local table with the same key names or that you should investigate a better pattern for your code.